# Eclipse android project project with facebook sdk as a maven dependency

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, maven

I would like to use Facebook Android SDK as a Maven dependency in my Eclipse project. After adding the dependency to the pom.xml I get the error:

> Failed to execute goal on project test-client-android: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.test.:test-client-android:apk:0.1.0: Failure to find com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:jar:4.6.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

Below is my pom.xml file. I have tried to do maven update, but nothing changes. What is wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>test-client-android</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>
<packaging>apk</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
        <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
        <version>23.0.1</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${env.ANDROID_HOME}/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mcxiaoke.volley</groupId>
        <artifactId>library</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.facebook.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>facebook-android-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.0</version>
    </dependency> 
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <sdk>
                    <platform>23</platform>
                </sdk>
                <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
                <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
            </configuration>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think exception is due to the android support library.
facebook is also use the android.support library so just exclude the android.support dependencies from the facebook dependencies like below.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>fr.avianey</groupId>
        <artifactId>facebook-android-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.18.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I have another error: Failed to execute goal on project test-client-android: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.test.:test-client-android:apk:0.1.0: Failed to collect dependencies at com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:jar:4.6.0 -> com.android.support:support-v4:jar:[22,23): No versions available for com.android.support:support-v4:jar:[22,23) within specified range.

Comment: @Jacek can go through below link is the sample code it will helpful you.https://github.com/avianey/facebook-api-android-maven

Comment: But what if I want to use the official, newer release? How to solve my problem in that case?

Comment: just change the updated version in the maven file. The exception due to the version of dependencies in android.support & facebook SDK library.

Comment: Can you give me a more descriptive answer? "Updated version" of what? I'm not sure what is happening, but after several maven cleans, updates and installs I have the same error as in the original question.